# How can i remove all emojs from a NSString

Tags: ios5, nsstring, emoticons

I need to remove all emoijs from a NSString.
So far i am using this NSString extension ...

```
- (NSString*)noEmoticon {
    static NSMutableCharacterSet *emoij = NULL;

    if (emoij == NULL) {
        emoij = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
        // unicode range of old emoijs
        [emoij removeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0xE000, 0xE537 - 0xE000)];
    }

    NSRange range = [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:emoij];

    if (range.length == 0) {
        return self;
    }

    NSMutableString *cleanedString = [self mutableCopy];

    while (range.length > 0) {
        [cleanedString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
        range = [cleanedString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:emoij];
    }

    return cleanedString;
}
```

... but that does not work at all. The range.length is always 0.
So the general question is : How can i remove a range of unicode characters from a NSString?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that in the above code the `emoij` variable is eventually an empty set. Didn't you mean to `addCharactersInRange:` rather than to `removeCharactersInRange:`?